# Deploy Web AppBuilder for external access

Tags: arcgis-server, sql-server, arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-web-adaptor

I am developing an app using Web AppBuilder within ArcGIS Online.

The data are hosted in in-house SQL Server, not in ArcGIS Online.

I have tested deploying in IIS, it works well, no issues.

While accessing the app externally through ArcGIS Online, the app does open, but the operational layers does not appear as these are hosted in SQL Server internally.

I need to deploy this app in a live environment so that the authorised groups can get access externally.

I reckon this has to be done through a web server, but can anyone please tell me the necessary steps to follow?

My worry and I am bit concerned about whether hosting data internally in SQL server would be an issue, or will this work?

Comment: you will need a reverse proxy for this to work externally  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy

Comment: ArcGIS firewall set-up with an IIS reverse proxy http://server.arcgis.com/en/web-adaptor/latest/install/iis/single-machine-deployment-with-reverse-proxy-server.htm

Comment: ESRI provide their own implementation of a reverse proxy as part of the ArcGIS for Server install. They call it a Web Adapter. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01540000028p000000

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestion and the links. Looks very useful! So, that means data hosting in a SQL server won't be an issue! Will try to follow the steps and will come back to you. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Mapperz it looks like you and or Dowlers have enough to post a answer on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Install a reverse proxy on a hosted web server in your DMZ. One comes with the licensing for ArcGIS for Server called "Web Adaptor".

Lock that server down with your Enterprise Windows Login.

Make sure CORS is enabled and your organizations ArcGIS Online URL is added to the header.

Adjust the security settings on your ArcServer to use Web-tier authentication.

Use the REST endpoints from the DMZ server to add items to ArcGIS Online.

Create the web app.

Make the data, the web map, and the web application available to everyone (public).

When anyone tries to open your application, they will be prompted to input their enterprise wide login to load the actual data.